# Font, font weight and size not saving in Photoshop PDF format

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have created a visual design of android app in photoshop. I have then merged all the non text layers, keeping the text layers on top and then saved in the file as Photoshop PDF, But when I open the file in Adobe Acrobat Pro and click edit text the font is getting replaced to Calibri font, Is there any way where I can export the PDF so that the developers cant easily get the font size and weights? or am I doing something wrong?

I am using latest creative cloud version of photoshop which Photoshop CC(2017)

In Photoshop
[image]

After exporting to Photoshop PDF and opening in Adobe Acrobat Pro and clicking edit pdf
[image]

Comment: The fonts need to be embedded.

Answer (score 1):

There are different font protocols and some do not work on the Adobe product line. Since you are running into this when you create a file in PS, and then save it to a PDF, it is the PDF that is not embedding the font. The only way around this is to 'Rasterize' the layer (under 'Type' menu). This turns it into an image layer and it no longer needs to be recognized by the PDF conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop isn't really meant to output directly to PDF, so saving as PDF from Photoshop is pretty restricting in comparison to exporting from either InDesign(Export to PDF) or Illustrator(Save As PDF).

It's pretty easy to make text edits off the PDF's you create within Id or Il if you don't outline the copy.